# まち: what's the difference between 町 and 街?

Tags: vocabulary, homophonic-kanji

My impression is that 町 tends to be used for smaller cities and 街 tends to be used for larger ones. Is this correct? If not, what *is* the difference?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is correct. According to 文化庁, 町 is similar to `town` whereas 街 is similar to `street` or `avenue`. 街 can also refer to a developed town with lots of streets and avenues, so to say.

For example, you can say センター街 (center-gai), but not センター町 (center-cho). This is because センター街 refers to "streets with small businesses". If there was a センター町, hypothetically speaking, a Japanese would imagine some area where small businesses are scattered here and there, rather than an area with a few streets with small businesses packed together.

Hence the different usage.

Comment: A gai is a more populated business district area with specialized services for example, Wall Street, with numerous financial institutions. A cho is a town, and provides municipal and generalized services.